# wrong result of an iteration related to replacement and comparing

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, filtering, code-review

We have two nested matrix and a code for replacement following an equality as:

```
m1 = {{{1, 2, 2, I}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}, {1, 2, 
 0, -I}}, {{3, 4, 4, I}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}, {1, 1, 2, 
 I}}};
m2 = {{{1, 0, 2, 1}, {3, 1, -2, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 2}}, {{1, 
 4, 4, I}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 4, -1}, {1, 2, 1, 1}}};
```

`m3` must be constructed by code:

```
m3 = ConstantArray[0, {2, 4, 4}];
Do[
   Do[
     Do[

        Do[

     If[m1[[k, i]][[1 ;; 3]] == m2[[r, s]][[1 ;; 3]], 
     m3[[k, i]] = m2[[r, s]], m3[[k, i]] = m1[[k, i]]]

         , {s, 1, 4}]


      , {r, 1, 2}],

   {i, 1, 4}],
{k, 1, 2}];
```

But because an iteration changes the condition of comparison of `m1[[k, i]]` I could not obtained the desired result which has to be as

[image]

As a matter of fact, the above code just bring `m1` again! How can I remove this problem and shorten the code instead of doing four iterations.?

Comment: What if you have multiple `{1, 2, 2, x}` elements in `m2`? Each with different x.

Comment: Good question, however this case could not be happened in the above example but it must exit the comparison. I mean the first one is important. the first meeting satisfies the comparison.

Comment: What is the first meeting depends of the way you iterate. And if you want different methods, you have to say exactly, what does it mean to be *earlier* in 2D matrix.

Comment: You are completely right. But the first meeting is being face to face of a sub_list in `m1` to a sub_list of `m2` and if the equality is ok the iteration must go to another sub_list of `m1` and start the next comparison and repalcement process

Comment: element #[[1,2]] will be before #[[2,1]] only if the outer iteration goes through rows and the inner on through columns. If you just replace `r` with `k` in table spec it will be different. That's what I was talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
m3 = m1 /. ({#, #2, #3, _} -> {##} & @@@ Flatten[m2, 1])
```

> ```
> {
>  {{1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 1, -2, 1}, {3, 2, 2, -I}, {1, 2, 0, -I}}, 
>  {{3, 4, 4, 0}, {1, 1, 4, 1}, {3, 3, 4, -1}, {1, 1, 2, I}}
> }
> ```

So basically we create replacement rules from `m2`, e.g. from `{1,0,2,1}` we get `{1,0,2,_} -> {1,0,2,1}`. Then we replace it in `m1`, if `{a,b,c,_}` matches, those 3 first elements you wanted, then the replacement is done, the rest of `m1` stays as it was.

---

*Edit*

As far as I remember your sublists are of length 8, then it may be more convenient to slightly modify approach to not type # #2... manually:

```
m3 = m1 /. (ReplacePart[#, -1 -> _] -> # & /@ Flatten[m2, 1])
```

Comment: I could understand what you said and deleted my comments. So much thanks for your answers and comments.

Comment: Nicely and wonderful!!!